# CIDR notation confusion

Tags: subnet

So we are using CIDR for subnetting
In that we just define the subnets by using /
SO my question is if I am using /24 it means that I have the last octet for host.
But if we use anything from /17 to /23 we say that we have borrowed bits from host space.
For eg: if use /17
`11111111.11111111.**1**0000000.00000000`
The 1st bit in the third octet is automatically considered as bit for subnet id 
So does that mean the subnet bit is octet specific
because if we take \23
`11111111.11111111.**1111111**0.00000000`
the subnet id then has 7 bits 
But the networking devices only treat the IP address as a 32 bit number then how is it able to understand where the subnet id bits start using cidr. Because in CIDR the network id and subnet id are combined???

Or is it so that IP addresses considered as 32 bit numbers have only network id portion and host id portion and the subnets are only visible in the dotted decimal notation...

I am newbie please explain in a way I can easily understand
Please Help
Thanks in andvance

Comment: Ok @Zac67 does that mean that subnet mask helps in determining the subnetid portion

Comment: The "subnetid portion" only exists in the exact moment when you are subnetting or supernetting. It is meaningless everywhere else - there's only a network portion and a host portion.

Comment: Ok that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Also in the above I aske whether it is octet specific while subnetting a network... What I mean to say is if we are using 1s and 0s in the same octet for mask it means the subnet id exists there

Comment: The octet notation is only for humans. For the network it's a 32-bit integer, as you've pointed out.

Comment: Ok I edited the comment when you were replying please check out.... Also Thanks for helping out so quickly

Comment: It's actually all in the question I linked above, check the *IPv4 math* section.